# geopandas plotting with legend filled up with slash lines

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, geopandas

I use different colors and patterns to show three counties on the PA map. The Centre County is represented by the slash lines using `hatch='\\'`. But I got difficulties to show such pattern on the legend.

I kind of know that this is not going to work, but I tried `Line2D([0],[0],color='white',hatch='\\',lw=4,label='Centre County')`, and got errors saying something like "hatch is not an attribute".

```
%matplotlib inline

import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,figsize=(8,8))

pa.plot(ax=ax,color='white',edgecolor='grey')
centre.plot(ax=ax,color='white',hatch='\\\\\\\\',edgecolor='black')
pike.plot(ax=ax,color='grey')
perry.plot(ax=ax,color='red')

LegendElement = [
                 Line2D([0],[0],color='red',lw=4,label='Perry County'),
                 Line2D([0],[0],color='grey',lw=4,label='Pike County'),
                 Line2D([0],[0],color='white',lw=4,label='Centre County')
                ]
ax.legend(handles=LegendElement,loc='upper right')
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you create polygons, the property `facecolor` defines the fill color. And to create correct legend for polygon features, `mpatches.Patch` is needed.

Here is the code that demonstrates how to use `facecolor`, and `mpatches.Patch`:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from cartopy import crs as ccrs

#fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,figsize=(8,8))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,9), subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()})

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
# cities = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_cities'))

asia = world[(world.continent == "Asia")]  #take Asia countries
asia.plot(ax=ax, color="lightgreen")

china = asia[(asia.name == "China")]
india = asia[(asia.name == "India")]
saudi = asia[(asia.name == "Saudi Arabia")]


ax.add_geometries(china['geometry'], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), \
                      facecolor='w', hatch='\\\\\\\\', edgecolor='k', label='China')
ax.add_geometries(india['geometry'], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), \
                      color='grey', label='India')
ax.add_geometries(saudi['geometry'], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), \
                      color='red', label='Saudi Arabia')

LegendElement = [
                 mpatches.Patch(facecolor='w', hatch='\\\\\\\\', edgecolor='k', label='China'),
                 mpatches.Patch(color='grey', label='India'),
                 mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='Saudi Arabia')
                ]
ax.legend(handles = LegendElement, loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

The output plot looks like this:

[image]